# Regarding getting date for third Monday of 2024

Tags: php, datetime

Can someone tell me why these 2 returning different dates?

```
$currentYear = 2024;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("january $currentYear third monday"));
echo "\n";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("third monday of january 2024"));
```

Comment: With the second version, it takes the ISO 8601 week into account when determining what the "third" Monday is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week